# How to get a Nuxt page to change the error page layout

Tags: nuxt.js

Is it possible to get a Nuxt page to indicate to the error page which layout it should use to render itself?

In my page, I use asyncData to try and fetch something from an API, like this:-

```
<script>
export default {
  layout: 'site',
  async asyncData({ $axios, error, params }) {
    try {
      const site = await $axios.$get(`/sites/${params.site}/`)
      return { site }
    } catch (e) {
      error({ statusCode: e.response.status, isSite: true })
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

In the error page that gets rendered, I want to be able to do something like this:-

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="errorPage" :error="error" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout(context) {
    // I WANT TO BE ABLE TO DETECT THAT isSite VARIABLE FROM THE PAGE HERE AND, IF IT'S true, RETURN THE 'site' layout
}
</script>
```

I know I don't have access to this in the layout function so I can't do exactly what I want to do but what are my other options? I can't see anything in the context that can help me - I could use the route.path to see if it *looks* like a site but I won't know if that axios call has come back to tell me whether it's a *real* site or not.

Hence why I want the page to do the call and tell the error page whether it's a real site or not.